# React child component have props always empty

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I have a problem. Probably it is simple but I'm not managing to resolve this issue.

App component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import SideMenu from './Components/SideMenu/SideMenu';
import Breadcrumbs from './Components/Breadcrumbs/Breadcrumbs';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />

                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <SideMenu />

                        <main role="main" className="px-4">
                            <Breadcrumbs nome="José" />
                        </main>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Navbar component

```
import React from 'react';

const navbar = (props) => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark p-0 shadow">
            <a className="mr-0" href="#">{ props.nome }</a>
                { 
                    console.log(props)
                }
            <ul className="navbar-nav px-3">
                <li className="nav-item text-nowrap">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
};

export default navbar;
```

My props is equal to {} on console and the props.name also.
There are no errors in the console.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Comment: You don't pass any properties to the `<Navbar />`, hence it's empty.

Comment: The real question is "why do you think Navbar would have props"? This code is doing exactly what it should be doing, what made you think it wasn't? Because that's a good signal that you should take a bit of time to run through the React tutorials on the React website, start to finish, so that you understand what's supposed to happen, based on what code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Navbar {...this.props} />
```

Please add it to your code at class App.

Answer (score 0):

As @zerkms said, I was not passing the props to the Navbar.
It was a simple lack of atention of mine.

Sorry and thanks for the help.